Are the eigenvectors of the generalised Laplace operator always periodic?
In $\mathbb{R}$ the eignevectors / eigenfunctions of the Laplace operator yield the fourier series, which, among other things, is made up of exclusively periodic functions.
If you have a Riemannian manifold $M$ you can always define functions of the form $M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and extend the laplacian via the Laplace-Beltrami operator.
Since this operator will necessarily be linear, it has a space of eigenfunctions and eigenvalues.
This makes me ponder, will the resulting eigenfunctions be periodic over the manifold?

You need to explain what you mean by periodic on an arbitrary manifold. But in general, the answer would be - definitely not.

As mentioned, it depends what you mean by periodic on an arbitrary manifold. Also one must be clear about what behaviour one wants these functions to have. On $\mathbb{R}$, regular exponential functions are eigenfunctions with positive eigenvalue but they are unbounded which is why generally they aren't as much of interest. On a compact manifold, the eigenvalues of the Laplace-Beltrami operator are negative and discrete, you can say these are "periodic" because the manifold is closed. A simple example would be the eigenfunctions of the Laplace-Beltrami on a circle $e^{in\theta}$.

But generally speaking, boundary conditions play the largest role in determining whether your functions are "periodic" or not.

@BaselJ. Could you expand on the comment about boundary conditions please?

@Makogan The Laplace-Bertrami operator is defined in the context of a boundary condition such as Dirichlet boundary conditions or Neumann boundary conditions. Different boundary conditions give different extensions of the Laplace operator, and therefore different eigenfunctions.
